# Issue when starting MATLAB from Terminal

Tags: kubuntu, matlab

I have installed a application (MATLAB) in Kubuntu and it is installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

If I type the name of the program in the terminal, it's not running and says that it did not find that command. When I go to that folder where it is installed and drag to the terminal and then it starts working.

I run this command `echo $PATH` in terminal and get this message:

```
/home/gurpreet/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

I have installed this program on my old laptop on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and was installed on `/opt` directory and when I typed `matlab` in terminal, it was working. Now this is not the case with Kubuntu.

Can anybody help me here as I am new user of Linux?

[image]

Comment: Please issue this command `ls /usr/local/bin | grep -i MATLAB`. If there is no output, then the binary file **MATLAB** is missing from folder `usr/local/bin`. It seems that the file missing in folders under your $PATH. Also issue commands `sudo updatedb` and  `locate -i MATLAB` to find out where about of `MATLAB`. You may also try `which` command.

Comment: when I run this command in terminal it works      /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab

Comment: when I run this command in terminal it works /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab

Comment: how should I set the path. I mean what should I type in terminal

Comment: Please set your path as ` /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin` in $PATH such as `export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:${PATH}`. This will vanish in next login. Please set this at your `~/bashrc` or  create a file in `/etc/profile.d/matlab.sh` and put this path command. Issue commands: **echo '#!/bin/bash' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/matlab.sh** and **echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:${PATH}' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/matlab.sh**. Then **sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/matlab.sh** followed by **source /etc/profile.d/matlab.sh**.

Comment: I just opened bashrc file and pasted this command at the end export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:${PATH}. This works in the terminal when I type matlab. Thanks a lot for your help. But can you please explain me why and how does it work .

Comment: After setting path, from command line you type `matlab`

Comment: It is .bashrc file, just there is `.` in front of it! its path is  ~/.bashrc file. It is my mistake. I missed a `.` in the path in my comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very quick reply. I tried google it many times but never got success. This method works for me. But I want to understand the   the logic behind it  i mean how does this path command works. why do we need to add the path of a  program installed in usr/local/bin. can you please explain it .

Comment: The answer is simple. Your binary **matlab** which is runnable is NOT under `/usr/local/bin`. Secondly, you have installed your software  package under **/usr/local/** and NOT under **/usr/local/bin/**. So PATH variable has no trace of your binary file **matlab**. So you should add entire `Matlab installation directory including bin` with PATH variable.

Comment: @Marmayogi That'd look like the valid answer, consider post it that way.

Comment: I think the usual way of doing it (in fact, I thought the MATLAB installer did this by default) is to symlink: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/matlab`

Comment: thanks a lot Marmayogi for your kind replies and I got your point. It means that we have to give the path of executable file.

Comment: In my early comment w.r.t **locate** command, the formatting was missing, thanks to @DK Bose for pointing this out. The commands to issue are `sudo updatedb` and `locate -ir /matlab$` to find out where about of **matlab** binary.

Answer (score 0):

A [MATLAB installation tutorial](https://medium.com/@ananyaagrawal125/install-matlab-on-ubuntu-18-04-b4403b489b4d) says that by default the MATLAB installer will create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`.

This means that you should be able to invoke MATLAB by typing `matlab` in the command prompt.

However, Questioner @GurpreetSingh has a MATLAB installation with missing symlink `/usr/local/bin/matlab` which is strange.

There are two solutions possible for this problem which are:

1. Put the `matlab` bin in the path through `PATH` variable as follows:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin:${PATH}
   ```

   This `export PATH` should be placed either in `~/.bashrc` file or in `/etc/profile.d/matlab.sh` (create this file if it does not exist)
2. Create the following symlink (Also refer @steeldriver comment):

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/
   ```

Questioner @GurpreetSingh installed MATLAB on `/opt` directory in the previous Ubuntu 16.04 system and it correctly worked because the `metlab` binary with `/opt` installation path should have been correctly set in `PATH` manually. Or else a symlink should have been created manually in `/usr/local/bin/` pointing to `/opt/MATLAB/R2018a/bin/matlab`.

Whereas in the present Kubuntu system, MATLAB was installed in `/usr/local` directory and the  `bin` path was NOT set manually. The symlink was also missing from `/usr/local/bin` directory which was really strange!

This is how the Questioner @GurpreetSingh has ended up with this problem.

That is it!